# Adding Users Without User Profile Sync

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile, user-profile-service, user-accounts

In SharePoint 2013, is it possible to give domain users permissions to a site without their profile being in the User Profile Sync set of users?

We are seeing a couple of issues - the users don't appear in the people picker so site admins cannot find them -

How do site owners add users when not synced?

We also see prompts for authentication for accounts that are not in the profile sync database

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Should not be a problem.
The user profile service application is also not available in SharePoint foundation and there you can also just give domain users permissions in SharePoint.

Comment: We see a couple of issues with this - the users don't appear in the people picker so site admins cannot find them - How do site owners add users when not synced? We also see prompts for authentication for accounts that are not in the profile sync database.